# Performance of Strategy Pattern example

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns

I am trying to implement in a different way the Strategy Pattern example shown in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).  Here’s my idea:

```
/** My wrapper idea for implementing the strategy pattern **/
class Calculator{
    static public final int OPTION_ADD = 1;
    static public final int OPTION_SUBTRACT = 2;
    static public final int OPTION_MULTIPLY = 3;

    //The following objects are the same as the ones in Wikipedia
    private Add add;
    private Subtract subtract;
    private Multiply multiply;

    public Calculator(){
        add = new Add();
        subtract = new Subtract();
        multiply = new Multiply();
    }

    public int execute(int a, int b, int option){
        switch(option){
        case OPTION_ADD:
            return add.execute(a, b);
        case OPTION_SUBTRACT:
            return subtract.execute(a, b);
        case OPTION_MULTIPLY:
            return multiply.execute(a, b);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

class StrategyStatic {
    public static void runStrategy() {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

        int resultA = calculator.execute(3,4,Calculator.OPTION_ADD);
        int resultB = calculator.execute(3,4,Calculator.OPTION_SUBTRACT);
        int resultC = calculator.execute(3,4,Calculator.OPTION_MULTIPLY);

        System.out.println("Result A : " + resultA );
        System.out.println("Result B : " + resultB );
        System.out.println("Result C : " + resultC );
    }
}
```

However when I run the code 800 million times, Wikipedia’s code snippet turns out to be 3% faster. Why?

Is creating and destroying the objects Add, Subtract and Multiply faster than creating only one wrapping object that with only one instance of each kind and just call each method depending on a chosen option at runtime?

Comment: What you implemented is no longer a strategy pattern.

As far as performance goes 3% is well within margin of error. It is hard to tell where this overhead is coming from without seeing both complete working examples.

Comment: @LeffeBrune, Why is it no longer a strategy pattern?

Comment: because Strategy pattern decouple the client that uses the behavior from implementation of that behavior. In the example on Wikipedia Context class knows nothing about the implementation of Add, Subtract and Multiply behaviors. In your examples those are tightly coupled with Calculator class.

Comment: @LeffeBrune Thanks! A full working example is in [GitHub](https://github.com/davidartplus/strategy-pattern). I still don't know why my snippet seems slower.